Methods to create large pdf documents with a very large number of annotations
I need to create large pdf documents with a very large number of annotations.   It combines text with a keyword in context index:  each significant word in the full text links to the corresponding word in the context index and back again.
On a linux desktop with 32Gb, using perl PDF::API2  I can successfully create a document of 1000 pages with 750 annotations on each page.   More than this causes the process to hang, probably after exhausting RAM.
I tried breaking documents into separate pdf files using GotoR annotations, but this apparently works only with Acrobat Reader which also complains about security risks.
Are there other perl or python libraries better able to handle this?

"using perl PDF::API2 I can successfully create a document of 1000 pages with 750 annotations on each page." To clarify your question and help us reproduce, please provide a minimal example of this script. See [mcve] for more information

If your annotations use named destinations, and you are able to choose the names, then cpdf (disclaimer, wrote it) should be able to merge the name trees and link the hanging references together upon merging. I can't guarantee its performance, though - it's quite a new piece of functionality.

I usually create .tex file and then run tex2pdf. Never had any issues.

Will pdf readers accept GoToR links without complaint if they have ssl signatures?

I can't give you an answer in Perl or Python and you didn't provide example code. However, in Ruby one can use HexaPDF and the following script to gauge execution time and memory usage:
require 'hexapdf'

HexaPDF::Composer.create('stack.pdf', skip_page_creation: true) do |c|
  c.page_style(:default, page_size: :A4) do |canvas, style|
    style.frame = style.create_frame(canvas.context, 36)
  end
  link = {link: "https://example.com", fill_color: 'hp-blue', text: "Ex"}
  1000.times do |i|
    puts "Creating page #{i + 1}"
    c.new_page
    c.formatted_text(Array.new(750) { [' text ', link.dup] }.flatten)
  end
  puts "Writing PDF"
end

That script creates 750 link annotations per page and a total of 1000 pages.
Using Ruby 3.3 with YJIT it takes a bit under 2 minutes and uses 1,838,884k memory as measured by /usr/bin/time. The resulting file is ~24MB big (~18MB for object streams, i.e. the annotations; and 5.5MB for the content streams) and contains 755,762 PDF objects.
